# Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation and let $v_1,\ldots,v_n \in V$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show that if $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is linearly dependent, then the set of images $T(v_1),\ldots,T(v_n)$ is linearly dependent. But I am not sure how to do so.

Comment: If $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...=0$ then $a_1T(v_1)+a_2T(v_2)+...=T(a_1v_1)+T(a_2v_2)+..=T(a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...)=T(0)=0$

Comment: $v_1,\cdots,v_n$ being linearly dependent means that the map $f:F^n\rightarrow V$ given by $f(a_1,\cdots,a_n)=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$ is not injective. Then the map $T\circ f$ is not injective either, which means that $T(v_1),\cdots,T(v_n)$ are linearly dependent as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $v_1,\dots,v_n$ are linearly dependent there are $a_1,\dots,a_n$, not all zero, such that $a_1v_1+\dots+a_rv_r=0$. Now map this equation by $T$ and use linearity to obtain $$a_1T(v_1)+\dots+a_nT(v_n)=T(0)=0.$$ And this is the condition for linear dependence of $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_n)$.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove the contrapositive.

Suppose that $\{T(v_1),\dotsc,T(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent. We wish to prove that $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is linearly independent. To do so, suppose that
$$
c_1\cdot v_1+\dotsb+c_n\cdot v_n=0
$$
Applying $T$ to this equation gives
$$
T(c_1\cdot v_1+\dotsb+c_n\cdot v_n)=T(0)
$$
Since $T$ is linear, it follows that
$$
c_1\cdot T(v_1)+\dotsb+c_n\cdot T(v_n)=0
$$
Since $\{T(v_1),\dotsc,T(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent, it follows that $c_1=\dotsb=c_n=0$. This proves that $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, as desired.